# java Swing best way to place panels within frame

Tags: java, swing, jtable, panels

i have 3 panels, panel1 has 3 components(ADD, Delete, Edit) JButtons, panel2(scrollPane) has jtable and panel3 again as (5 JTextFields, 5JLabels). when I add all panels into frame panel3 components shows paritialy only means (4JTextFields) only visible within frame. for panels I used BorderLayout for frame.add(panel2,BorderLayout.SOUTH) , frame.add(panel3,BorderLayout.CENTER); panel1, panel2 shows all of components, but panel3 shows partially only. could you please suggest me precisely what layout should I use, for panels, and how to setsize for my frame to accomodate all panels(components)?   clearly?

`

```
          frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(updatePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setSize(850, 500);
```

`

Comment: `JFrame#pack` - Also, a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) speaks a thousand words...

Comment: how about starting with reading a decent tutorial, f.i. the one referenced in the swing tag wiki?

Comment: i used frame 's setsize method, so it hides my panel partly. once i removed frame.set Size method and used pack method as said by @MadProgrammer, thanks genius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`Window#pack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack())

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts
>   of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height of the window are
>   automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is less than the
>   minimum size as specified by the previous call to the setMinimumSize
>   method.
>
> If the window and/or its owner are not displayable yet, both
>   of them are made displayable before calculating the preferred size.
>   The Window is validated after its size is being calculated.

**Updated with example**

Without a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (working example), it's impossible to fully diagnose your problem.  Let me demonstrate...

So, based on your description, I can create this without any issues...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestPack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestPack();
    }

    public TestPack() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TopPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(new MiddlePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.add(new UpdatePanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TopPanel extends JPanel {

        public TopPanel() {
            setBackground(Color.red);
            add(new JLabel("I'm on top"));
        }

    }

    public class MiddlePanel extends JPanel {

        public MiddlePanel() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"A", "B", "C"}, 5))));
        }

    }

    public class UpdatePanel extends JPanel {

        public UpdatePanel() {
            for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                add(new JLabel(Integer.toString(index)));
                add(new JTextField(5));
            }
            add(new JButton("Button"));
        }            
    }        
}
```

But obviously, you're doing something different.  Take the time to update your question with a working example, otherwise there's nothing more we can possible do

Comment: *"please give code for your answer"*  3 hours before your comment, @MadProgrammer suggested you post code (an SSCCE) explaining the problem.  You ignored that, yet are expecting code in an answer?!?  -1

Comment: frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(updatePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); my updatePanel not visible fully geeks.

Comment: And what is `topPanel`, `updatePanel` and `middlePanel`?  I can't possibly diagnose your problem without a runnable example that demonstrates your problem - most likely causes - `null` layout or overridding `getPreferredSize` of one or components...

Comment: previously i mentioned tat updatePanel has 5 Jtextfields, 5 Jlabel, 1 jbutton. middlePanel displays my jtable. my two panels showing components perfectly. My last panel, i.e updatePanel is partially visible. button not visible when i load my frame. frame.pack() also not helpful. it not changed any of old output.

Comment: What layout manager is the `updatePanel` using?  It would be easier if you could provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), or we could be going backwards and forwards like this for some time...

Comment: @MadProgrammer plz provide the steps me , how to provide a SSCCE , many times i came across this buzz word. the layout is BorderLayout.south for updatePanel, and BorderLayout.North for topPanel, and BorderLayout.Center for middlePanel. middlepanel(has Jtable).

Comment: thanks @MadProgrammer it gives me expected GUI for my problem. Excellent code.